# X-Forwarded-For response equivalent

Tags: http, proxy, haproxy

Loadbalancers/Proxies tend to add an `X-Forwarded-For` header to requests. Is there an equivalent response header for this, identifying the server that handled the request?

Maybe `X-Forwarded-To`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "standard" header for that as it is a rather rare use-case to actually want to identify a backend server to the final client in a header.

In HAProxy, about the only way possible right now is to use the [cookie](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#cookie%20%28Server%20and%20default-server%20options%29) setting in backend servers which can then return a cookie back to the client identifying the server. But that has the potentially unfortunate side-effect that the client returns the cookie back in subsequent requests which HAProxy then uses for sticky sessions.

Depending on your use-case, it might be enough to just check the HAProxy logs. For each request, it states there which backend and which server handled the request.

Comment: I actually set it manually on the app server. Just wanted to know if there is a standard header for this. I need it only to check if haproxy balancing works as expected.